# Values in one field in a table from lookup in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, lookup

I am using Microsoft Access 2010
The tables I am trying to perform this lookup on are

```
StockCount
```

Which Contains

```
Unit No
Event ID
Product Name
Price
Qty Open
Qty Trnasferred
Qty Closed
Wastage
Qty Staff
Qty Sold
Total Amount Taken
```

And `Transfer`
Which Contains

```
ID
Transaction
Event ID
Unit No
Docket ID
Product Name
Amount
```

In `StockCount.[Qty Transferred]` field needs to be a lookup that calculates the sum of all `Transfer.Amount` Where the Product Name, Event ID and Unit No matches in both tables.

The current SQL Command I have got

```
SELECT Sum(Transfer.[Amount]) 
FROM Transfer, StockCount 
WHERE Transfer.[Product Name] = StockCount.[Product Name] 
    AND Transfer.[Event ID] = StockCount.[Event ID] 
    AND Transfer.[Unit No] = StockCount.[Unit No];
```

This has been placed under lookup option of the Qty Transferred field,

- The display control is list box
- The row source type is Table/Query
- The row source is the SQL Command above

After this, no values are changing and I am unsure why.

Comment: Am I missing something about Access?  That's only a `SELECT` statement, which in no version of SQL actually changes data (well, barring some bizarre trigger).  Normally you'd need an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`...

Comment: Are you using Sharepoint? If not, it is a bad idea to use lookups in tables. You can use a combo box in the form to control the table or a query to display the data.

Comment: @X-Zero, I am extracting the data from the Transfers table - the sql statement is entered into the row source. I am not sure if this is correct please reply if you have any suggestions

Comment: @Remou I am not using sharepoint. I am developing a stock management system in C#, it is based on a stadium where there are multiple retail units, transfers of stock can be done between units so this is for monitoring any stock movements. What would be your suggestion on keeping an up to date count of stock transfers in the stock count table.

Comment: If you have Access 2010, [data macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff973807.aspx) and / or [calculated columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff945943.aspx) may suit, otherwise, you may be best just using a query (view) for the information.

Comment: There is an article that may be of interest [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/116142). You should consider getting rid of the spaces in your field (column) names. All those square brackets will drive you mad eventually :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SELECT statement selects records but does not change any data. Your SELECT statement returns only one single value, the total of all amounts. Probably you want to calculate the totals per `[Product Name]`, `[Event ID]` and `[Unit No]`. A SELECT query doing this looks like this

```
SELECT
    [Product Name], [Event ID], [Unit No],
    Sum(Amount) AS SumOfAmount
FROM
    Transfer
GROUP BY
    [Product Name], [Event ID], [Unit No];
```

Unfortunately, this query cannot be turned into an UPDATE query in Access, since it contains a `GROUP BY`. An UPDATE query would need to join this query to the `StockCount` table. The resulting query would not be updatable.

I see two solutions to this problem

1. Fill a working table with the result of this query and update from this table
2. Update the `StockCount` table programmatically by looping through the result of the query above.

---

I show the first approach here. First create the working table.

```
twrkTotalAmount
---------------
Product Name
Event ID
Unit No
SumOfAmount
```

Then clear the table (it might contain records from a previous run)

```
DELETE * FROM twrkTotalAmount;
```

Now Insert the sums

```
INSERT INTO twrkTotalAmount
    ([Product Name], [Event ID], [Unit No], SumOfAmount)
SELECT
    [Product Name], [Event ID], [Unit No], Sum(Amount)
FROM
    Transfer
GROUP BY
    [Product Name], [Event ID], [Unit No];
```

Now you can perform an UPDATE query

```
UPDATE
    StockCount
    INNER JOIN twrkTotalAmount
        ON (StockCount.[Product Name] = twrkTotalAmount.[Product Name]) AND
           (StockCount.[Event ID] = twrkTotalAmount.[Event ID]) AND
           (StockCount.[Unit No] = twrkTotalAmount.[Unit No])
SET
    StockCount.[Total Amount Taken] = [SumOfAmount];
```

Comment: That looks fantastic, I will try this Thank you for the time and effort you have put into the answer